# Using Graph Theory to solve an IMO 2021 problem

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, contest-math, bipartite-graphs

Here is a question from IMO 2021:

> Let $n>100$ be an integer. Ivan writes the numbers $n,n+ 1,\dots,2n$ each on different cards. He then shuffles these $n+ 1$ cards, and divides them into two piles. Prove that at least one of the piles contains two cards such that the sum of their numbers is a perfect square.

Algorithm:

1. First find those duplets whose addition will lead to perfect squares.
2. Next try to form a bipartite graph from those duplets.

Proof to show:
A bipartite graph is not possible.

Am I going correctly? Basically, I want to solve this using graph theory. It will be very helpful for me if I get some insight on how to approach this more accurately.

EDIT:-
If I am able to check whether the graph is 2-colorable or not then my
job will be done.

Taking an instance
[image: see this]

It is not possible here to make different colors for adjacent.

> Hence Proved

Comment: Maybe. That’s a certain point of view on the problem. Perhaps even a good one. Now, what would be the next step?

Comment: A graph is bipartite if and only if it contains no odd-length cycle.

Comment: @saulspatz that's the checking process of bipartiteness. I am asking about the proof. how should be the approach

Comment: Did you see where it says "if and only if"?  If you prove there must be an odd-length cycle, then the graph is not bipartite.

Comment: I think DFS can do that

Comment: You have the right perspective, but need to continue with the logic. Here’s one hint. If $x$ is in one group then $k^2-x$ is in the other.  Similarly for $k+1$ and $k-1$. What happens if you repeatedly apply this?

Comment: @Eric okay. an odd length cycle will be generated for each path

Comment: Suppose $n=101$.  Then if $\frac{18^2}{2}+1=163$ is in one set then $17^2-163=126$ would need to be in the second, so $18^2-126=198$ would need to be in the first, and $19^2-198=163$ would need to be in the second, but it is already in the first.  Then show something similar can happen for all larger $n$

Comment: Almost all solutions boil down to showing that there is a triangle, for which there are much better approaches than using the graph theoretic representation. I have not yet seen a purely graph theoretic solution (though I would love to see one), in part because the restriction on "numbers between n and 2n" does exclude certain triangles from consideration as the vertex wouldn't exist.

Comment: As far as I saw, but didn't check, somebody on AoPS found explicitly seven cycle in this graph.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/142687/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4209107/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

> You can find an odd cycle in the graph of the form $(2k^2-4k, 2k^2+1, 2k^2+4k)$.